# jQuery - add/remove str on change

Tags: jquery

I have, on my own site, some links to RSS feed's... like this:

```
ALL
example.com/rss

NEWS
example.com/rss?type=1

ARTICLES
example.com/rss?type=2
```

At the same page I want to insert some filter... so I have a select:

```
<select class="rss-list-platform">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="1">Xbox</option>
<option value="2">PlayStation</option>
</select>
```

I am looking for a jQuery code that will add "&platform=val" to the original link, however, if the "All" option on the select is picked... we should remove the "&platform=val" if there is any.

Currently I have the following code, but it keeps adding over and over the text... and don't removes it.

```
$(".rss-list-platform").change(function(){

        var ref_this = $(this);
        var original_str = "";

        $(".rss-list input").each(function(){

            original_str = $(this).val();
            add_str = original_str + "&platform=" + ref_this.val();

            $(this).val(add_str);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and try to use it. It is built for the thing you are trying to accomplish. The code would look something like this:

```
var url = "http://your.site/something";

$(".rss-list-platform").change(function() {
    var params = $("#id-of-form").serialize();
    $("#id-of-tag-containing-url").text(url + "?" + params);
}
```

You need to add a name to the select tag in order for this to work.

The serialize() method works on form as well as input/select/textarea tags. So another example of how to use it is $(":input").serialize(). Perhaps that makes it easier in your scenario.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit further? Trying to serialize() the select $(".rss-list-platform").serialize() doesn't output nothing.

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle so it uses serialize(). Have a look at it and hopefully you will find it useful! http://jsfiddle.net/PMCWw/2/

Answer (score 1):

Run a quick check before you add:

```
original_str = this.value
    add_str = original_str + "&platform=" + ref_this.val();
    var check_str = "&platform=" + ref_this.val();
    if (this.value.indexOf(check_str) > -1) {
        //string is already there!
    } else {
        $(this).val(add_str);
    }
```

And to remove it, inside your `change`

```
if (this.value == 1) { //1 is for All
    $(".rss-list input").each(function(){
        var index = this.value.indexOf("&platform=");

        //remove it if it exists
        if (index > -1) this.value = this.value.substring(0, index);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I did it right... but it don't works. I've added it all on jsfiddle... can you check it and tell me how, please? here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3MUn/1/